# font-weight ниже 500 игнорируеться

Tags: html, css, шрифты

Поставил кастомный шрифт с google fonts. Проверил есть ли все версии шрифта для любого веса.
Ничего из предыдущих стилей не перебивает (проверил на отдельном файле). Браузеры (chrome,mozilla,edge) просто показывают один и тот же стиль для шрифтов с font-weight:100-500;600-700 и 800-900. Также проверил , возможно дело в шрифтах - нет . Проверил с дефолтным шрифтом - результат такой же .

Юзаю вот это код для изменения веса

```
font-weight:200;
```

Подключение шрифта :

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,900&display=swap"rel="stylesheet">
```

В CSS:

```
font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
```

Comment: Покажите как шрифт подключен. И какой собственно шрифт

Comment: @AlexeyTen Уже исправил вопрос

Comment: Суть вашей проблемы заключается в том, что вы включили стиль через кавычки, но это было необходимо без кавычек

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут всё работает

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,900&display=swap"rel="stylesheet">

<style>
p {
    font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: 200;
}
</style>

<p>Hello! I'm Montserrat font @ weight:200</p>
<p>Привет, я шрифт Montserrat жирности 200</p>
<p style="font-weight:400">Нормальная жирность</p>
```